# How can I offload a build to a server to stay productive?

Tags: build, distributed

I have several large projects that I work on. Depending on the project and options, build times are from 10-100 minutes long, rendering me useless for that time.

I do have a few extra computers laying around however. Is there anyway that I can configure these computers as 'compile nodes' so that I can still work while a build is going on?

I've heard of software plugins for Visual Studio for doing this, but I've seen the price tags. I'm looking for something that's preferably free or under $100-ish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set up a free [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) continuous integration build server.

Comment: TeamCity looks very impressive. I'll definitely look into it more.

Answer (score 4):

Too much [slacking off](http://xkcd.com/303/)?

Answer (score 2):

You *could* just hook them up and set up a local area network couldn't you? If you wanted to just do it quick and dirty. Set up a compiler on each machine, and just send the code through your local series of tubes, compile on one of your build machines and continue working.

Comment: I honestly think that TeamCity is less work than writing your own scripts to do this.

Comment: Really? I would just copy it over and run make on the remote machine... Maybe increment and reset a variable to alternate build machines... In any case, it's just one "first thing to jump into your mind" solution, yours is certainly valid too.

Comment: TeamCity takes about 30 minutes to set up (less if you've done it a few times) and then everything will be automatic.

Comment: yeah, but more to download as well - I mean, it takes maybe a minute to hammer out a quick batch script to do a file copy and run make. But as I said, that's just a quick and dirty, probably error prone solution, and yours is probably a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

I love Hudson (http://hudson-ci.org/). It is feature-reach, stable and free. It's primarily focused on Java, but can be easily be used to build non-java projects

Comment: Very nice! I like the look of this! I'll let you know if I end up picking this

Comment: Link is broken. Is this still a thing?