# Visual Studio - Build on another machine

Tags: visual-studio, build

This will probably be marked as duplicate, but I did not found relevant post.

My main computer is a laptop (because of the need of transportability) and I happen to have a secondary - powerful - desktop at my office.

I use it as CAD station and I work on it through my laptop with Teamviewer. There is a direct ethernet link between them.

Now, would it be possible to use the powerful desktop to perform the build task of Visual Studio, using the IDE on the laptop for coding, generating the binary on the powerful computer and executing on the laptop (with debug) ?

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014548/10226538

Comment: That is more about compiling nodes where you have many computer working together. I'm just talking about a single computer. @AnthonyMansour

Comment: I suppose this is *possible*, but you'd have to write a lot of code to automate the process.  With the amount of work involved, it's not worth the effort, IMO.  You could set up a build server, but it doesn't meet your last requirement out of the box (executing the binary on the laptop).

Comment: It would be easier to simply RDP into the more powerful computer, and do your work there.